# How to merge array of individual object into one single array-Js/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to merge 2 objects into an array. I have a structure like this:

[image]

The object could be an empty or may have data. I'm trying to combine the object from he `self.series2` into `self.series`, so as to look like:

[image]

where: the second object is the object from the `self.series2`. Is it possible?

Js:

```
var series = [{
  "Name": "abd",
  "Surname": "Agrawal",
  "id" : 7349879837,
  "address" : "7923street"
 }];
 var series2 = [{
  "Name": "abd23",
  "Surname": "desia",
  "id" : 7349879837,
  "address" : "7923street"

  }];
merge: function(){
   var self = this;
   var self.series = {};
   //here im not sure how to do a `forEach` for 2 objects
   $.each(series, function (i, o) {
       $.extend(self.series, o)
   });
   $.each(series2, function (i, o) {
       $.extend(self.series, o)   // in this case it overwrites the first object with the second one.
   });
});
```

How can i loop in through both the objects so that at the end in `self.series`, i have both objects from series and series2?

[image]

Any ideasss??? Thanks!!

Comment: have you looked into the [concat method of Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)? `self.series.concat(self.series2);` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in Javascript and de-duplicate items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you have two arrays, and want a merged one. So maybe you try with Array.concat?

```
var series = series1.concat(series2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.series = [self.series[0], self.series2[0]]`